# scanning permissions of an application in android before its installation

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm totally new to android,and I'm struck into the question...
Is it possible to scan the permission list of an android application before its installation on mobile. For example, when the dialog box is shown for the list of permissions to the user,I want my application to scan those permissions and then after scanning suggest installation to the user..

Answer (score 1):

> For example, when the dialog box is shown for the list of permissions to the user,I want my application to scan those permissions and then after scanning suggest installation to the user

This is not possible.

You can find out *after* the installation that an app was installed (via an `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast).

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape the Android Playstore HTML page of the chosen app and get the permissions that way.

Comment: Thank you sir..for your reply..I hope this helps me...:)